# Ad Hoc distribution UI Slow

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, cocoa

I ran my code on simulator, Iphone 5 with xcode connected just fine.
When I deployed to an Iphone 4s device, the scrolling is lagging, clicking is lagging by a seconds.

These are my steps to deploy.
1. Create provision profile on apple developer site which include my iphone 4s device.
2. Import into XCode organizer - Provision.
3. Set Code Signing to Distribution.
4. Distribute it through email.
5. Double click on IPA to install the App on device.

Any reason that caused slowness?

Comment: Did you debug/run it on the simulator using the iPhone5 like 4 inch Retina display output or on the REAL iPhone5 hardware via the debugger?

The speed of the real hardware + debugger should indeed be lower than the speed of the same app on a undebugged device. 
The simulator runs with the full speed of your Mac, so it's speed does not tell anything about the feel on a real device.

Comment: An addition to the comment above : you could try a "time profiling" with Instruments to see what part of code is lagging and fix it.

Comment: I ran it with or without debugger on iphone 5 (real device) and the speed is OK. But not in Iphone 4 without debugger (ad hoc distribution). The scrolling, the back action seems to be slower then iphone 5